# Importing Java projects that use custom build tools

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

The team I'm working with use their own custom implementation of Ant (it has a Java wrapper for writing the build files) for building projects. I'm currently using Vim for all my editing but would like to use Eclipse for my next project I will be starting soon. I haven't a lot of experience at using Eclipse and my initial attempts to import the project files haven't worked. I basically need to know if there is a (relatively) simple way of importing generic non-eclipse Java projects. In an ideal world I would be able to keep using the team's idiosyncratic ways of building projects and running unit tests but with the refactoring and context sensitive capabilities of Eclipse (plus the other features Vim is somewhat weak on). The key thing here is that my team need to be able to build my projects without using eclipse.

If using Eclipse is going to require too much deviation from the current conventions of my team I will just keep using Vim as my primary editor.

Comment: These are exactly problems why I would consider migration to Maven or Gradle. Cost some time and pain at first, but saves huge effort and money in future. + You wouldn't need to maintain your home made build system anymore.

Comment: That ain't gonna happen. My boss's boss wrote the Jant (Java Ant) tool we use and he suffers from mild Stockholm syndrome regarding their continued use of it. I.e. if I suggested we change tools he would reply 'over my dead body'.

Answer (score 0):

I rementer that in bad old days (without Ivy/Maven/Gradle) we were handling dependencies of Eclipse projects via UserLibraries feature.

If you go to Window -> Prefenrences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries, you can create/import/export XML containing your dependencies. (Can't remember if this handles relative paths). This file can be stored in source control.

You can than right click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library... -> User Library and pick your create user library XML

So whenever developer see strange compiler issues after pulling out source code, he needs to import new user libraries XML.